# Use absolute path or relative path in React Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

All:

I am pretty new to React Router, when I follow its offical tutorial at lesson 7:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/07-more-nesting

When it comes to route params like:

```
// index.js
// ...
<Route path="/repos" component={Repos}>
  <Route path="/repos/:userName/:repoName" component={Repo}/>
</Route>
```

It starts to use absolute path, I am wondering :

[1] How does React-Router decide to use abosulte path or relative path, is it only because the path starts with slash "/"(one thing I find out is: once I add slash to a relative path at the beginning, that path turns into absolute path, no matter what its parent routes are.)?

[2] Is there a way I can use relative params path route? If not, then what is the point of the parent Route whose path is "/repos"?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. React router currently uses absolute paths, [but they are working on relative routes](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5127)
2. If you want relative routes, it looks like people are getting the current route from the match param, and then appending a route to it. E.g.,  `<Route path={match.path + '/more/stuff'}/>`

In the example that you gave, the point is that whenever the current path contains `/repos` there will be some content (the list of links to repos generated by `component={Repos}`) that will be visible. When the path is `/repos/:userName/:repoName` it will continue to show that content because the path still matches `/repos`, but it will also show a particular repo's content (`component={Repo}`).